# How to build search engine (web application) using Lucene.Net & .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lucene.net, lucene

I want to develop a search engine for my department intranet site to let colleagues searching document for download and information in html page.

I proposed to use Lucene.Net & .Net C#/VB to build up the searching (web application). But it is hard to found tutorial/sample on it, i don't know how to do the indexing on document, html page content...

I am looking for related tutorial/reference. Thanks.

Comment: This might not be what you are after (hence posting it as a comment). `SolR` is built on top of `Lucene` and [`solrnet`](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) is a client for `SolR`. In [this](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/SampleApp) you get a basic web application which might make things simpler and point you in the right direction.

Comment: The main problem your going to face is that Lucene was dead for a long time while the current version is a massive leap forward from version 2.0 most of the examples on the net are based on that.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://jsprunger.com/getting-started-with-lucene-net/) covers the very basics but lucene and search is a big topic, Id start here and ask more questions as you go.